# Why this code isnt working in jupyter notebook? JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes

Tags: json, jupyter

```py
import json
fopen=open(r"c:\users\admin\documents\data.json")
data=json.load(fopen)
print(data)
fopen.close()
```

I am using Jupyter notebook and I am trying to print data from a JSON file.
the error:

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)

Comment: The exception suggests that the file doesn't contain valid JSON. Where did the JSON come from? Can you show a sample of it?

Comment: The error poinds to the `load` method, right?  Make sure the json file is properly formatted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

windows path(s) are useless as they have escape character in them

"r" here is raw string

```
import json 
fopen = open(r"c:\users\admin\documents\data.json")
```

credits to @hpaulj for solution

Comment: That `r`  isn't the read mode (which comes after the filename if used).  It's python to take the string in 'raw' form.